# Multiple Instances of applets in panel

Tags: linux, linux-mint, panel

After upgrading to Linux Mint 19.3, I'm getting multiple instances of applets in my panel. The ones I've noticed so far are the update manager and bluetooth applets. When I close one of them, they both close.  When I reboot, they both come back.  How can I get rid of the duplicates?

[image: Duplicate applets]

Answer (score 0):

Well it didn't take too long, but I discovered that I had an applet called XApp Status Applet enabled, which in the description says that it hosts all the system tray icons for applications which use XApp Status Icons. Apparently if you have any of those particular applets already enabled, along with the XApp applet, you will get a duplicate. I honestly don't remember enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem in Linux Mint 20.3. I wanted to report that removing the xapp status applet from the panel also worked for me. I right clicked at the left edge of the leftmost icon in the panel. Depending on where exactly you click, the menu for xapp status applet or the notification area applet opens. They seem to be on top of each other, causing the problem. Check that you are in the menu for the xapp status applet (Look into "about"). Unclick "Lock To Panel" from the menu. Do the same thing once more and click "Remove From Panel" to remove xapp status applet. I did not get any more double icons after doing this. If you mess up, "Reset All Panels" and start over.